# How do you compare data in two columns and select which is outputted?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, selection

I've been working on this code in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('processedblock2.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['index', 'x','y','z'])#in order for this to work needed to clen up the csv file a lot


#data.columns = pd.read_csv('pdbtesttrimmed.txt')
#this sets up a boolean of true or false
add = df.x >= df.y
result =[add]
if result = True:
    data.to_csv('pdboutput2.csv')
```

It outputs to the pdboutput2.csv Boolean data when I want the add result to be the condition of whether or not data is inputted.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import pandas as pd 
 #creating dummy dataframe with two columns 
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[3,2],[4,6],[6,7]], columns = ['A','B'])
```

now when we are running df.A > df.B , it will give boolean value

[image]

to access true cases, we can simply pass the boolean value in dataframe
     df[df.A > df.B] , rather storing it in list and than checking the condition .

```
 data = df[df.A > df.B]
 #op
```

[image]

```
 # now it can be exported..
 data.to_csv('outputfilename.csv')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)